# Why am I getting empty expression data from GEO?

Tags: scrnaseq, gene-expression, sratoolkit, geoquery, geo

I am trying to analyze the scRNAseq data from [this study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867418307931?via%3Dihub). In their Method section they write:

> The accession number for the RNA and DNaseq data reported in this
> paper is GEO:
> [GSE116237](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE116237).

When I go ahead and try to pull this data in R using `GEOquery`, I am faced with a data frame with no features (i.e. no genes). The following code

```
library("GEOquery")
gse <- getGEO("GSE116237")
eset1 <- gse[[1]]
eset2 <- gse[[2]]

print(dim(eset1))
print(dim(eset2))
```

yields

```
Features  Samples 
       0      184 
Features  Samples 
       0      681
```

I also didn't manage to download the data manually; I get an error message when trying to unzip the `.zip` files or [get redirected to SRA Run Selector](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/study/?acc=PRJNA477841&o=acc_s%3Aa) from which I also didn't manage to figure out how to download stuff.

Am I missing something or are these files simply corrupted? The paper is published in Cell, so I would assume this data is, to some extend, legit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure the data is legit, you are just approaching it incorrectly. getGEO is an application for microarray data, not for digital count data such as (sc)RNA-seq, therefore what you aim to do is simply not possible by design. Unless you want to start from the raw reads why not taking the at the file named `GSE116237_scRNAseq_expressionMatrix.txt.gz` provided at the bottom of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE116237?